# Best way to change an existing Interface api method to return an Object instead of void?

Tags: java, api, interface, refactoring

I have an existing design based on an Interface which exposes an API method, which currently returns void. And there are many different implementation classes which implements this interface. But, now I want to make a change so that few of these implementations should return an Object. Obvious solution seems to be: to make all the implementations return 'Object' and expect the returned value to be ignored wherever not required. But is there a cleaner and better solution for such a re-factoring?

Is there any design pattern that could be applied here which would make the design better, in case I have to make change to all the existing implementations, whether required or not.

Illustration below:

```
//the interface
public interface CommonInterface{
    public void commonMethod();   //this is where I want to change the return type 
                                      //to 'Object' for some of the implementations
}

//the factory
public CommonInterface getImplInstance() {

     CommonInterface implInstance = instance; //logic to return corresponding instance
     return implInstance;
    }

//the implementation (there are multiple implemenations like this)
public class Impl1 implements CommonInterface {
   public void commonMethod() {
     //some logic
   }
}
```

Comment: The fact that your returning a value from some and not others screams that these implementations are representing two different concepts/operations.  Maybe if you give an idea of what these classes do, we can make better suggestions. Constantly checking for a subinterface and downcasting can get messy, as well as always checking for a null result.

Comment: These classes are for handling the processing of commands recieved from command line. Each class is having the specific logic for the type of command it handles. The interface provides a common api through which you can handle any type of command at runtime. And suddenly there is a usecase where some commands will need to return something( not just display the result), so that this return value can be used for some other purposes. Basically, trying to reuse the existing code.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a new interface, CommonInterface2, which implements the new method. This requires changes to the "few of these implementations" rather than the "many implementation classes".

```
  public interface CommonInterface2 extends CommonInterface {
      public Object commonMethodAndReturn(); 
  }
```

Implement this only in the subset of implementations that return an object.

```
 public class OneOfTheFew implements CommonInterface2 { ... }
 public class OneOfTheMany implements CommonInterface { ... }
```

Test for the new interface only where a return value is required.

```
 public void foo( CommonInterface ci ) {
    if ( ci instanceof CommonInterface2 ) {
        CommonInterface2 ci2 = (CommonInterface2) ci;
        ...
    }
 }
```